# Cannot get to the login screen, but a yellow colored terminal

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, login

I installed xubuntu yesterday, and it now cannot reach to the login screen. It shows a yellow colored terminal. I don't really know what the problem is this, and rebooting does not work. It keeps getting into the same terminal.

Please check out the screenshots. Thank you.

[image]

After entering password

[image]

Comment: After entering the password type`startx` and you should get a desktop. A reboot may then fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can now get into the desktop. But it still shows the terminal every time I reboot. Is there a way to bypass the terminal screen and go to the login session or desktop straightway?